# What are the specs of the CPU at Digital Ocean

Tags: cpu, digital-ocean, ovh

I'm trying to make a comparison between DigitalOcean's and OVH's dedicated server CPUs. I know OVH's gaming servers are probably more performant than those on DigitalOcean. I just wanna know how that would translate in terms of actual usage.

**EDIT**

Maybe I should clarify a bit.
OVH tells you exactly what CPU you're getting. An example of gaming dedicated server would have the following CPU specs

```
Intel  i7-6700K - 4c/8t - 4GHz /4.2GHz
```

All I could find about DigitalOcean servers is that they are between 2.0 and 3.0 Ghz.

Also, in case it's not already clear by the question I'm asking, I'm not very familiar with the concepts of CPU performance per se. I'm not sure how an Intel  i7-6700K differs from an Intel  i7-7700K in terms of concrete performance and load that the CPU can handle. There are forums discussing these points, but in terms that only confused me further.

I know this should be very basic and apologize for my ignorance, but any references or plain explanations would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Digital Ocean, assume you're using linux: https://askubuntu.com/questions/26393/getting-processor-information This will help get you the information.

More pertinently, they probably don't share it **deliberately**, because they don't want you to benchmark it and complain when your 'cpu' is not as fast as the 'core' should be. (They don't want you to see the processor model and mistakenly think it will do a lot more than they will have it do for you because of some benchmarks for said processor you are aware of). Cores are the physical cpus, whereas 'cpu's are virtual ones.

Example: Hosters normally take e.g. 20 virtual machines, each of which will have 2 cpus assigned to it, and run them on a Hypervisor (hardware which manages some Virtual Machines) which has 10 cores. This means that if every VM ran a cpu intensive task simultaneously, each VM would only have half a core. Hosters try to balance Hypervisors so that they have a mixture of VMs which they have noticed use lots of CPU, and ones which have not.